# Blurred vision after exercising

Tags: exercise

I often get blurred vision after exercising. (moderate cardio)  Sometimes it is right after, other times, it is about 15 minutes after exercising.  It lasts about 30 minutes.  My blood pressure is on the low side but is good.  I am anemic.  Could it be the anemia causing the blurred vision?

Comment: You might need some iron, bananas and tomatoes are great sources of iron

Answer (score 1):

[Possibly](http://www.livestrong.com/article/194299-what-are-the-causes-of-blurry-vision-and-dizziness/)

> Severe anemia may lead to dizziness and blurred vision because of reduced oxygen delivery to the brain and low blood volume.

Overall, I'd recommend checking with your doctor.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities here, but, the most common culprits are that you are either not drinking enough water, or vice versa, you are drinking far too much water(The latter is less likely). Dehydration and over hydration both can cause blurred vision, and working out hard would just make it worse, which would explain why it goes away a little while after. There could be other medical/vision problems occurring here, but I would say the chances are greater that you are suffering from a hydration related issue. Let me know if you believe you aren't drinking enough water or are drinking too much of it. I hope this helps.